# WPF,MVVM Binding ViewModel-Property to nested UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have 2 user controls called "MyTree" and "MyGrid".
I have another user control called "Content" which has a "MyTree" and "MyGrid" in it.
I have a window with a tab control.
Each tab item contains "Content". Tab items are added dynamically.
So how can I add item to "MyGrid" when I create a tab item dynamically.
I use MVVM patterns and INotifyPropertyChanged events
Iam setting the item source as some property.

Now My  "ContainerPanelViewModel" has

```
private string pro11 ;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enterd loop");
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
        public string pro1
        {
            get
            { 
                return pro11; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (pro11 != value)
                {
                    pro11 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("pro1"));
                }

            }
        }
```

And i  have another view model which has a

```
ObservableCollection<ContainerPanelViewModel> RootNodeTabCollection
```

And Iam adding

```
 RootNodeTabCollection[0].pro1 = "abc";
```

But the label content is not getting updated

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
```

is false always..and not entering to the loop.
The message box is not displayed any time

Comment: Post some code, it's hard to envisage what you're describing.

Comment: Due to some security issues I am not able to show the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a collection of ViewModels where each of them will be a DataContext for a certain Tab. Then this ViewModel should have another collection that can be used as DataContext for your Grid or Tree.

Comment: OK..Thanks for the hint...By mistake i was keeping the collection of views instead of viewmodels..I hope that will solve my problem..Thank you both

Comment: After doing that I got some other error....After setting the property of a viewmodel from another view model my "PropertyChanged != null" is always NULL..So the UI is not updated..what may be the reason?                 <Label Content="{Binding Path=pro1,Mode=TwoWay}" />

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you wanted to say. Could you please write here an example?

Answer (score 1):

If `PropertyChanged` is null it means that nothing is bound to the view model. In your XAML you need to bind a property to an instance of your view model using the `{Binding ...}` syntax for anything to happen when you update a property on the view model.

You probably already have some bindings in place, but you can debug these bindings to learn more about why a binding is failing. There are several ways to do that but one method is to add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the binding. E.g.:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Items, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

WPF will then write binding trace information for that particular binding to the debug window.